Swiftのモジュールインターフェースにコメントを記したい
■ Xcode Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
■ Swift Version 5.8.1
■質問内容
モジュールのインターフェースに記載された構造体，クラス，メソッド，プロパティなどに説明書きを追加したいのですが，可能でしょうか．
■詳細・手続き
友人に Protocol とDelegateについて説明するためにマルチプラットフォームのDelegateStudyというパッケージを作成しました．
次にMacOSのコマンドラインツールプロジェクトDelegateStudyProjectを作成しそこからDelegateStudyパッケージをPackage Dependenciesに追加しました．
DelegateStudyProjectのmain.swiftファイルにてimport DelegateStudyを記載しました．
下図がmain.swiftの内容です．

DelegateStudyパッケージの仕様を見るためにDelegateStudyにカーソルを合わせてJump to Definitionを押したところ次のような画像となりました．

これではインターフェースしかわからず，どのように実装すれば良いのか伝えられません．
パッケージ側を修正してこれにコメントを追加することはできないのでしょうか．
例えば次のような記載にしたいです．
// デリゲートのためのプロトコル
public protocol GameDelegate {
    // ゲームの名称
    var gameName: String { get set }
    // ゲームの準備をするメソッド
    func setUp()
    // ゲームの処理を開始するメソッド
    func start()
    // ゲームの処理を終了するメソッド
    func end()
}

■意図
ソースコードを見れば良いというのはわかりつつ，友人が本質的に理解できているか試すために，具体的な処理内容は伏せた形でこちらのモジュールインターフェースに実装のための最低限のコメントを記し，それだけを見て実装してもらうことを実施したい次第です．

自己解決いたしました．
コードのコメントアウトを /// で行うことによりメモを追記できました．
解決にあたり参照したファイルになります．
https://github.com/swiftlang/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift#L26-L62

//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
//===--- AdditiveArithmetic -----------------------------------------------===//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//

/// A type with values that support addition and subtraction.
///
/// The `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol provides a suitable basis for additive
/// arithmetic on scalar values, such as integers and floating-point numbers,
/// or vectors. You can write generic methods that operate on any numeric type
/// in the standard library by using the `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol as a
/// generic constraint.
///
/// The following code declares a method that calculates the total of any
/// sequence with `AdditiveArithmetic` elements.
///
///     extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
///         func sum() -> Element {
///             return reduce(.zero, +)
///         }
///     }
///
/// The `sum()` method is now available on any sequence with values that
/// conform to `AdditiveArithmetic`, whether it is an array of `Double` or a
/// range of `Int`.
///
///     let arraySum = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5].sum()
///     // arraySum == 16.5
///
///     let rangeSum = (1..<10).sum()
///     // rangeSum == 45
///
/// Conforming to the AdditiveArithmetic Protocol
/// =============================================
///
/// To add `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol conformance to your own custom type,
/// implement the required operators, and provide a static `zero` property.
public protocol AdditiveArithmetic: Equatable {


